# How to execute terminal commands through scala

Tags: scala, csv

I am trying to access a CSV file in Scala for validating the data in it. I succeeded in that. Now i want to dump all of that CSV file into a MongoDB database using the `mongoimport` utility of MongoDB. But I don't know how to execute this command from Scala. So, please can anyone tell me how to execute terminal commands from Scala?

My mongoimport command is as follows:

```
$ mongoimport -d dbname -c Colname --type csv --file Address.csv --headerline
```

Plese, suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [scala.sys.process](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.sys.process.package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be something like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val process: Process = Process("echo Hello World").run()
println(process.exitValue())
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Tatiana i found it very useful. .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.process` standard library.  Check the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) for a complete description.